# Custom TCA Fields not visible in Frontend

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I've created a Backend Extension and extended fe_user by 4 additional fields.

I am Using TYPO3 7.6.13.

The 4 custom fields are visible in backendlists, but not the fields are not available in frontend.

Is there any "special" list I need to extend with my fields? My TCA Configuration as follows.

```
ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('fe_users', $temporaryColumns);
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'field1', '', 'after:image');
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'field2', '', 'after:field1');
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'field3', '', 'after:field2');
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'field4', '', 'after:field3');
ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'fe_users',
    'field1, field2, field3, field4'
);
```

Is there more todo or did I ran in some sort of bug?

Comment: For me it is not exactly clear what the "frontend" part of your extension is. Do you have an extbase model of your FrontendUsers that should be output in a Fluid template? In what file did you place the code above? I assume you placed it in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php`. You added field1 - field4 in line 1-4 but also added them in line 5 of your code example, again. Appearantly there is another custom extension that added the fields vtiger_..., because them are not default fields of  TYPO3

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear about that. I've edited that vtiger thing, that was a mistake in the question. I've a extbase model for FrontendUsers and a fluid template for the output. The problem i've is that field1,2,3,4 are not available. The code abobe is placed in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php. Is line 5 not necessary?

Comment: Did you extend database table fe_users with 'field1' ...?

Comment: Yes, I did that, including the sql file. Editing these 4 fields in backend (List moduie) works like a charm. I've also upgraded to TYPO3 7.6.18 a few minutes ago, just so be sure... but no luck. When I debug in fluid with <f:debug>, i only get the standard fields like username, password, usergroup, name, etc.pp - not my 4 new fields.

Comment: Have you added the new fields as properties to your model? Note: if the fields are named in the database and TCA with underscores (e.g. `my_field`) they have to be named in lower camel case in your model (e.g. `protected $myField`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend an existing extbase model the folllowing steps are needed:

- Add the fields to your database in ext_tables.sql
- Add the fields to TCA in Configuration/TCA/Overrides/table_name.php

This should be enough to use the fields inside the TYPO3 backend.
For frontend rendering your need two more steps:

- Extend the Extbase model (Property, Getter and Setter)
- Tell extbase to use your new model with TypoScript: `config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes`

As far as I understand your did the first 3 steps, but maybe missed the last one?

Full example (ext_typoscript_setup.txt, normal TypoScript file should also work):

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser {
                subclasses {
                    0 = YourVendor\YourextNamespace\Domain\Model\YourClass
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This should be enough for many tables, but `fe_users` uses the `recordType` field. To configure this you need the following TypoScript snippet (same file as the `config.tx_extbase` config):

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
         YourVendor\YourextNamespace\Domain\Model\YourClass {
            mapping {
               tableName = fe_users
               recordType = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This forces extbase to ignore the `recordType` and always use your model.

Documentation/Full example (including `recordType` explanation): https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/5-modeling-the-class-hierarchy.html

Comment: ext_typoscript_setup.txt did it like a charm! awsome - thx m8! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the fields to the model. In your domain you will have a fe_user repository which will be mapped to the real fe_user table.

If you add fields to fe_user you have to add them also to your fe_user model.

Did you think about that?

Comment: Hi Stephan, yes. I've created a model for all 4 fields. Classes/Domain/Model/FrontendUser.php. Both there, Setter and Getter. That's why i am wondering. I can't see what's propably missing.